# XBIM Web Viewer - Calculate HTML position from WCS

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, xbim

I'm trying to put an overlay over the top face of the bounding box of selected object. What I'm doing is:

1- Get the vertices of the bounding box top face in WCS, from center point

2- Translate each vertices into point in HTML space

3- Put a div at the point in HTML space

However, only the center point is correct, other vertices are off. Like in the screenshot, the blue floor is the selected object.
[image]

Here is the code:

```html
// Translate a point from WCS to HTML space
    public getHTMLPosition(position: vec3) : number[] {
        // transformation matrix from projection pMatrix and view mvMatrix
        const transform = mat4.multiply(mat4.create(), this.pMatrix, this.mvMatrix);
        // apply transform to position
        const glPosition = vec3.transformMat4(vec3.create(), position, transform);
        const glX = glPosition[0];
        const glY = glPosition[1];

        // translate from 0-1 space to html pixel position
        const htmlX = (glX + 1) / 2.0 * this.width;
        const htmlY = this.height - (glY + 1) / 2.0 * this.height;

        return [htmlX, htmlY]
    }
```

```html
document['getHTML'] = () => {
    const elements = viewer.getProductsWithState(State.HIGHLIGHTED);
    if (elements !== null) {
        const bbox = viewer.getProductBoundingBox(elements[0].id, elements[0].model);
        const center = BBox.centre(bbox);

        const wcs = viewer.getCurrentWcs();

        const boxInView = BBox.getSizeInView(bbox, cameraDir, cameraUp);

        const upleftLocal = vec3.fromValues(bbox[0], bbox[4], bbox[5]);
        const uprightLocal = vec3.fromValues(bbox[3], bbox[4], bbox[5]);
        const downleftLocal = vec3.fromValues(bbox[0], bbox[1], bbox[5]);
        const downrightLocal = vec3.fromValues(bbox[3], bbox[1], bbox[5]);

        const upleft = vec3.add(vec3.create(), upleftLocal, wcs);
        const upright = vec3.add(vec3.create(), uprightLocal, wcs);
        const downleft = vec3.add(vec3.create(), downleftLocal, wcs);
        const downright = vec3.add(vec3.create(), downrightLocal, wcs);
       
        const glCoords = [upleft, upright, downleft, downright, vec3.fromValues(center[0], center[1], center[2])];

        glCoords.forEach((c, index) => {
            const htmlCoord = viewer.getHTMLPosition(c);
            const cube = document.createElement('div');
            document.body.appendChild(cube);
            cube.setAttribute("class", `cube${index}`);
            cube.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            cube.style.position = 'absolute';
            cube.style.width = '20px';
            cube.style.height = '20px';
            cube.style.borderRadius = '30px';
            cube.style.left = `${htmlCoord[0] - 10}px`;
            cube.style.top = `${htmlCoord[1] - 10}px`;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I mistook how BBox are stored.

0, 1, 2 are x, y, z of minPoint.

3, 4, 5 are width, height, depth.

So the resulting points should be:

```
const upleftLocal = vec3.fromValues(
  bbox[0],
  bbox[1] + bbox[4],
  bbox[2] + bbox[5]
);
const uprightLocal = vec3.fromValues(
  bbox[0] + bbox[3],
  bbox[1] + bbox[4],
  bbox[2] + bbox[5]
);
const downleftLocal = vec3.fromValues(bbox[0], bbox[1], bbox[2] + bbox[5]);
const downrightLocal = vec3.fromValues(
  bbox[0] + bbox[3],
  bbox[1],
  bbox[2] + bbox[5]
);
```